# using the results from query doing further calculations with these results in the same query giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, error-code

i have written the query like this 
 and i want to caluculate further with these results that to all in  single query

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As totalcontractamountperiod ,
   DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS exppayments,
   30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS monthlyamount, 
   (totalcontractamountperiod/monthlyamount) as exppayments, 
   member_Id 
FROM membertomships;
```

is it possible that all comes in single query using mysql

but it was giving error like this

```
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'totalcontractamountperiod' in 'field list'
```

can anyone have idea about this

MODIFIED CODE :  I have done like this by using subqueries....

```
SELECT  
  EXPPAYMENT WHERE EXPPAYMENT =(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As totalcontractamountperiod ,
  DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS exppayments , 
  30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS monthlyamount , 
  (totalcontractamountperiod/monthlyamount) as exppayments, member_Id 
FROM membertomships);
```

but it was giving error like this

```
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EXPPAYMENT =(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_En' at line 1
```

and this is the modified query and added two more functions to the query but sill it was giving error

```
SELECT 
  Total,
  (datdiff-1) as diff,
  ceil(ExpPayments-Total) AS datdiff,                 
  ExpPayments, 
  MonthlyAmount, 
  (Total/MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
  member_Id 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*    memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total,     
  DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
  30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
  member_Id
FROM 
  membertomships 
) as SourceTable;
```

error like this

```
                     Error Code: 1054
                     Unknown column 'datdiff' in 'field list'
```

would you pls help

```
               SELECT 
                SourceTable.Total,
               ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff,                 
              ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) -1 as diff,
                       ADDDATE(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-   SourceTable.Total) -1) MONTH), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - SourceTable.memberToMship_DueDay DAY) As expdate,
              SourceTable.ExpPayments, 
             SourceTable.MonthlyAmount, 
           (SourceTable.Total/SourceTable.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
            SourceTable.member_Id 
        FROM 
        ( 
              SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*      memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total,     
          DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
          30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
           member_Id
          FROM 
         membertomships 
      ) as SourceTable
```

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'SourceTable.memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'

Comment: Does this query execute successfully? And if possible post how are you using it after that.

Comment: @sweko NO.. it was giving error Error Code: 1054

Comment: @sweko and further calculation is also same as this one....

Comment: @cularis   no i hav taken that in that query

Comment: @cularis   i   have taken from this query            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As totalcontractamountperiod

Comment: Define the calculated fields you need in a subquery and use them in the outer query like you did in your current query.

Comment: how to define them in a subquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll abreviate some of the column names as they are a bit on the long side, so the query can be more clear:

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,EndDate)* ChargePerPeriod As Total,
        DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),DueDay),StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,    
        30* ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(EndDate,StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount,
--->    (Total/MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2,     
        member_Id  
FROM membertomships;
```

The problem is in the pointed row, as you are using the `Total` and `MonthlyAmount` in the same column list that defines them. I know it look like it should work, but it's illegal to use SQL like that.

What you could do is:

1. Repeat the condition that defines the values (and hope that the database will only calculate it once), like

this:

```
SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,EndDate)* ChargePerPeriod As Total,
        DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),DueDay),StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,    
        30* ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(EndDate,StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount,
        (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,EndDate)* ChargePerPeriod / (30* ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(EndDate,StartDate))) as ExpPayments2,     
        member_Id  
FROM membertomships;
```

1. Rework the expression like a subquery. You get the calculations done in one step, and than use those results for further calculations, like

this:

```
SELECT Total, ExpPayments, MonthlyAmount, (Total/MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, member_Id  from
(
  SELECT  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,EndDate)* ChargePerPeriod As Total,
          DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),DueDay),StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,    
          30* ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(EndDate,StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount,
          member_Id  
  FROM membertomships
) as SourceTable
```

BTW, two columns in the original query are named ExpPayments, I renamed the second ExpPayments2.

Comment: sweko i added two more functions to query at this time it was showing error and i have added the modified code ...

Comment: @user682417 - about `datdiff` - you are doing the same thing again, using `datdiff` at the same it's defined. You might have to add another subquery, just like the first time.

Comment: If you find the subquery within a subquery within a subquery confusing (and it is), you might want to create some views, that will help you clarify the data model in your head.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  derived.totalcontractamountperiod,
  derived.exppayments,
  derived.monthlyamount,
  (derived.totalcontractamountperiod/derived.monthlyamount) as exppayments2,
  derived.member_Id
FROM
( 
  SELECT  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As totalcontractamountperiod ,
    DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS exppayments,
    30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS monthlyamount, 
    (totalcontractamountperiod/monthlyamount) as exppayments, 
    member_Id 
  FROM membertomships
) derived
```

You've got the same problem with the modified code. It should be:

```
SELECT 
  SourceTable.Total,
  ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) AS datdiff,                 
  ceil(SourceTable.ExpPayments-SourceTable.Total) -1 as diff,
  SourceTable.ExpPayments, 
  SourceTable.MonthlyAmount, 
  (SourceTable.Total/SourceTable.MonthlyAmount) as ExpPayments2, 
  SourceTable.member_Id 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate)*      memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total,     
  DATEDIFF(GREATEST(NOW(),memberToMship_DueDay),memberToMship_StartDate)/30 AS ExpPayments,
  30* memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod / DATEDIFF(memberToMship_EndDate,memberToMship_StartDate) AS MonthlyAmount, 
  member_Id
  FROM 
    membertomships 
) as SourceTable
```

Comment: hi stevie but it was giving error like this                      Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15

Comment: if i have removed the symbol like this one ";" at membertomships it was giving another error like this ...                                  Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: stevie G i added two more functions to query at this time it was showing error and i have added the modified code ...

Comment: stevie it does not work if we add one more sub query ..... i have posted have an another question...

Comment: Steive I have did this still i got error like this                 Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'SourceTable.memberToMship_DueDay' in 'field list'  i have included modified  question in this post

Comment: Does that column exist in the membertomships table?